# Magento 2: set different languages for the back-end and storefront

Tags: magento2, store-view, language

I have recently set up a **Magento 2** shop. I need to set the part that is visible to the customers in one language (German) and the backend (Dashboard) in another language (English).

I have not managed to see such an option in the admin section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download de_DE.cvs file follow the next links

github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE

create an i18n directory in magento/app and create in the directory splendid/de_DE/ put there the download files configure language Stores > Configuration > General > Locale Options

[image]
after run
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

whit this the frontend is en german language if you want change the language in the dansboard of admin go to user and change the language in user account settings  for which you want.

[image]

and put you password and save config user;

Answer (score 0):

You can set the language for the frontend in `Stores > Configuration > General | General > Locale Options > Locale`

[image]

The backend (admin/dashboard) will be in English by default and won't change if you change the locale for the frontend, but if you want to change the admin language you can do so for an account by clicking `Account Settings` (top right corner in the admin).

In there you can set the `Interface Locale`.

Hope this helps.